# Object Detection project with OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv, computer-vision

I am trying to make an Object Recognition software for my final year project using `OpenCV`. After studying quite a lot about this field, I found out the plan of action should be this:

- Extract features from a lot of images.
- Create a training dataset from the extracted features.
- Label the dataset.
- Make the machine learn from the dataset.
- Test the model.

I started from a single image. I was able to extract features from the image using `SurfFeatureDetector` class of OpenCV (`simple_matcher.cpp` program given in the samples). I saved the detected `KeyPoints` in an XML File using the following code:

```
SurfFeatureDetector detector(400);
vector<KeyPoint> keypoints1, keypoints2;
detector.detect(img1, keypoints1);
detector.detect(img2, keypoints2);
FileStorage fs("test.xml", FileStorage::WRITE);
write(fs, "data", keypoints1);
```

Now I am stuck at this point. I am not able to understand how do I create the training dataset from these features? And what should be my next step? Or, is my plan of action correct?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Format and content of a training dataset depends on what you want to recognize. Please, specify your goal more clear.

Comment: I want to detect objects in an image, which may be multiple in number. So, i want to create the training set with, for example, 100 images with a ball, 100 images with a tree, and so on.

Comment: For starters, do [this](http://blog.davidjbarnes.com/2010/04/opencv-haartraining-object-detection.html).

Answer (score 4):

you would probably need to do these following steps.

1. Find out and zero in on a feature detection and extraction algorithm you want to   use(SIFT,SURF,ORB, there are few more).
2. Detect and extract features. you should be storing descriptors extracted from a descriptor extractor in your xml files.
3. add those descriptors to a trainer such as bowtrainer to create a dictionary.
4. Train your classifier

You can find lot of examples [here](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/master/samples/cpp) and you can watch [this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WEzm7L5zoZE) video if you want to realize something similar in your project.

Comment: i used the BOWTrainer to create a vocabulary. But now, I cannot understand what to do next with the vocabulary. Please help.

Comment: Now,start training your classifier. You can look at [this](https://github.com/royshil/FoodcamClassifier/blob/master/train_bovw.cpp)example

Answer (score 3):

First, it would be easier to use popular datasets, for example, from [here](http://pascallin.ecs.soton.ac.uk/challenges/VOC/). It allows you to not spent time on images and gives a possibility to compare your results with state-of-the-art.

Second, it is not easy task. I recommend you to read [papers related to the PASCAL VOC](http://pascallin.ecs.soton.ac.uk/challenges/VOC/pubs.html).

If you want to do the first try, read about bag-of-words model, for example it is pretty short and nice explanation what to do in the [blog of the SO user @gillevi](http://gilscvblog.wordpress.com/2013/08/23/bag-of-words-models-for-visual-categorization/).